# How can my published folder automatically update when I compile my ASP.NET Core 3 application?

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, deployment

I have an asp.net core 3 application deployed on IIS. I made this by publishing the website on a separate folder, and reference that folder when I added a new application in IIS. It works, I can access it from different computers, but this folder doesn't get updated when I'm doing modifications and compile the project. I always have to publish it whenever I make small modifications. How can I overcome this situation?

This is how my folder looks like after publishing my project.

[image]

Comment: That’s exactly why we say it is a publishing process. If you want something more automatic, learn to use continuous integration and continuous deployment.

Comment: Thank you Lex Li ! I didn't know about these until you said it. :)